Search history - clear / disable
In relation to a retail website search bar. Is it necessary to have the option to disable search history if there's an option to clear it?

Necessary is a strong word but what if the user wants to disable search history moving forward? It'd be annoying to have to clear it out every time.

Depends on how the disable and clear search history functions work.
